# Funcanimation is not animating line Graph/time series from fixed excel file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, graph, time-series

I am trying to animate the time series using Python with an excel file. Data looks like:

[image]

However, it is not animating the fixed graph, only stored the graph in gif format:

```python
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_excel(r'D:\new result\Results\SCA\all_inone_final.xlsx')
    x = data['Date']
    y1 = data['LAC']
    y2 = data['GAC']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(x, y1, label='LAC')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='GAC')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=100000)
ani.save(r'D:\new result\Results\SCA\live_plots\_'+'_SCA_4.gif', writer='imagemagick')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

any recommendation help? TIA

Comment: It is not animated because you are not using the `i` value, which updates at each cycle. The point is: what do you want to animate? What do you want to see changing, frame by frame?

Comment: How to use `i` value? I have two curves to show y1 and y2 which I want to make in animation. How to proceed ?

Comment: Ok, but which property of the curve will change during the animation?

Comment: With time(X) y should change. I am trying to compare two curves (Y) with time(X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
# import section
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# dataframe creation section
N = 400
Date = [datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2002', '%b %d %Y') + timedelta(days = x) for x in range(N)]
x = np.linspace(0, N/10, N)
LAC = np.sin(3*x) * np.cos(6*x)
GAC = np.cos(x) * np.cos(5*x)

data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': Date,
                     'LAC': LAC,
                     'GAC': GAC})

# figure preparation section
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (16, 8))

# animate function definition section
# note the use of i
velocity = 1
span = 7
def animate(i):
    plt.cla()

    x = data['Date'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]
    y1 = data['LAC'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]
    y2 = data['GAC'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]

    ax.plot(x, y1, label='LAC')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='GAC')

    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    ax.set_ylim([-2, 2])
    plt.tight_layout()

# animation function call
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1, frames = N-span)
plt.show()
```

which give this result:

[image]

Since I do not have access to you data source, in the "dataframe creation section" I create a dataframe in order to perform the animation, you have to replace it with your data.
Note the use of `i` in the `animate` function: I used it to slice the `x`, `y1` and `y2` arrays in order to plot only a portion of `span` elements long. As animation is going on, the `i` increases, so the slice of the arrays flows along them and the plot shows the trend of `y1` and `y2` over time.
I do not know if this is what you want, because you did not specify what you want to see changing while the animation is going on, however I hope this code could help you to understand how to create one.

---

**EDIT**

This the code with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

data = pd.read_excel('data_comparison.xlsx')
velocity = 1
span = 7

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (16, 8))

def animate(i):
    plt.cla()

    x = data['Date'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]
    y1 = data['LAC'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]
    y2 = data['GAC'][velocity*i : span + velocity*i]

    ax.plot(x, y1, label='LAC')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='GAC')

    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    ax.set_ylim([0, 65])
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1, frames = len(data)-span)
plt.show()
```

which gives this animation:

[image]

(I cut the animation because its size is too big, over 2 MB. However you can run the code above and you will get the same animation)

---

**EDIT 2**

Fixed x axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

data = pd.read_excel('data_comparison.xlsx')
velocity = 1
span = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (16, 8))

def animate(i):
    plt.cla()

    x = data['Date'][0 : span + velocity*i]
    y1 = data['LAC'][0 : span + velocity*i]
    y2 = data['GAC'][0 : span + velocity*i]

    ax.plot(x, y1, label='LAC')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='GAC')

    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    ax.set_xlim([data['Date'].iloc[0], data['Date'].iloc[-1]])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 65])
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1, frames = len(data)-span)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer = 'imagemagick')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can slice the arrays with `[0 : span + velocity*i]`: the start is fixed while the end changes as animation goes on. To fix the axes I used this lines:

```
    ax.set_xlim([data['Date'].iloc[0], data['Date'].iloc[-1]])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 65])
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please have a look over a shorter version of data (I have much longer in time). [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8dc1f13411d82f679eb6c7f4190ae99020200608202417/d04590271b96b49f379bffaf9ead270320200608202454/8fd233] How to put this excel file data into code??

Comment: Could you please click **try this fix** in the message.

Comment: I have uploaded it again [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8dc1f13411d82f679eb6c7f4190ae99020200608202417/f7daef]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked:) If I could ask more How can I fix the x-axis without moving horizontally?  I want to move two lines in a fixed x-axis. something like this [https://saralgyaan.com/posts/python-realtime-plotting-matplotlib-tutorial-chapter-9-35-36/].